# Google Play won't show Update button if the app was previously installed by downloading the APK manually

Tags: android, google-play

Google Play won't show Update button. I suspect this has to do with the fact the app was previously installed by manually downloading the APK file from a site.

Is there anyone who can confirm this behavior and/or has any idea how to deal with this? We develop Android apps for our customers and would really like to have them try out the app before publishing it to Google Play- so we have to deal with this transition.

Comment: Does Google Play show 'Open' and 'Uninstall' buttons for your app?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that it is possible to allow a user to update an app that they have installed from a non-market source. This is because when you purchase an app Google links that app with your gmail account, allowing you to install the app on multiple devices.

One reason that they do not allow users to install updates to apps they have installed from non-market sources is piracy, because that would allow users who have not purchased apps to get free updates.

Also, this question is slightly off topic

Comment: Google always check if the paid app you are trying to update you actually bought.

Comment: The application is not paid. It offers paid content via in-app purchase, but can be installed from market freely. Market still doesn't offer upgrade.

Comment: Even if the application isn't paid then you will not be able to update it via Google play as long as it as installed from other sources

Comment: @JanHudec is it other resource problem? becuase when I have  a `v1.0.5` at `Play Store` and install `v1.0.4` from `Android Studio`, it's showing "open"

Answer (score 1):

Google Play will not offer you an update if the version you have installed is the same or higher as on Google Play.

If you want to update app from Google Play that was previously installed manually make sure that those apps has the same certificate and package names.

Comment: The application uses the same name and certificate. Google Play considers it "installed". The installed version is definitely lower than the one on Play. Play still considers the application just installed and does not offer updating it.